# Losing suggested edit points when questions are deleted

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, deleted-questions

3 questions were deleted because of being closed and off-topic.  I had edits on various places on those posts and lost points for the edits that were approved by the community.  Is this the way it is supposed to work, or is this something that should be where if the post is so old it doesn't get reverted?

I no longer can get reputation by editing posts and it has been quite some time since that happened.

It hasn't been quite a year since the edits but am still curious how others think this should work as well.

Comment: This question is about 6 reputations points out of 9.3k, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is supposed to happen.  An edit is only recorded on an existing post, and it is removed when the post is deleted.  The rep with edits cannot be retained, but it'll come back (just like anything else) if the post ever gets undeleted.

As @nhgrif has said in the comments, it's only 6 rep points.  For someone with your rep count, I doubt it should really matter.  Heck, I lost 4 points myself, and I'm kinda surprised it was that low.

Comment: it's going to be more than 6 points if you keep running around deleting all the posts I edited... LOL JK  I was more curious about the functionality of it all.  if the post was older than a year or had the right amount of up votes would it still take my points away?

Comment: @Malachi: If a post is over 60 days old *and* has a score of 3 or more before deletion, the rep is retained, including the 15 rep from a checkmark.

Comment: gotcha I didn't get the and part before I thought it was one or the other.. thanks